# How do I add an HTML element to this line of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following line of code in my javascript:

```
$('form #fullvalue').val('Monthly Payment: '+fullvalue2+'pm');
```

What I need to do is wrap the words "Monthly Payment" in a span element.

I coded it like this (see below), but then it doesn't pick up that it's an html element, it outputs the html as text:

```
$('form #fullvalue').val('<span>Monthly Payment: </span>'+fullvalue2+'pm');
```

*** UPDATE ***
Sorry for the confusion, but I'm not trying add a span to a text field. It's for a line of text inside my form, but not a text or text area field - it's just a normal line of text that appears inside the form. The "fullvalue2" javascript code outputs a result from a calculator in the form. And I'm simply trying to add the text "Monthly Payment", which should be wrapped in a span, before "fullvalue2"

Comment: What is the type of  `#fullvalue` element.

Comment: If you're trying to put this in a form field, you can't use HTML.  If #fullvalue is not a form field, use `.html()` instead of `.val()`.

Comment: What is the span for? Why do you need a span in a form control element?

Comment: Please see my post, I just updated it to clear out confusion. I'm NOT trying to add a span to a text field.

Comment: Where is the HTML that your JavaScript is trying to modify? Can't help if you don't post that

Comment: Your question conflicts with itself. You're saying, that you're not trying to add an element to a form control element, but you also say, that you can see the result of setting the _value_  of an element. That's not possible, if the element was not a form control.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I missunderstood how javascript applies it. No worries then, I'll make another plan. Thanx for your help anyways.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

The value of a form control can only be plain text.

If you need markup, then you need to use something more complicated (such as a div with `contentEditable` set and a pile of JS to read it back when you want to use the data).

Comment: What about textarea?

Comment: @jrummell — A textarea is a form control. The value of a form control can only be plain text.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.

Comment: Please see my post, I just updated it to clear out confusion. I'm NOT trying to add a span to a text field.

Comment: @Shtarley — What are you trying to add it to then? If `val()` does anything then it must be a form control of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

To set HTML of a node, use [`$.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), [`$.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) is for form fields.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var fullvalue2 = $('#val').val();
  $('form #fullvalue').html('<span>Monthly Payment: </span>'+fullvalue2+'pm');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form> 
  <input id="val" value="123.34"/>
  <span id="fullvalue">Original value</span>
</form>

<button>Change HTML</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `label` element to include descriptive text about an `input` or `textarea` element within a `form` , `for` attribute at `label` element to reference `id` of `input` or `textarea` associated with `label` element